# ArcGIS Map Export - Series of Attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, mapping

I am working with ArcGIS 10.7 and can not find a solution to my problem.

I have got a shapefile with 1000 datasets and 20 different species of plants. Now I want to export the 20 species maps in series. 
It is always the same extent just records of the species vary.

I worked with Data Driven Pages a lot but I just cant see how this has to be done.

Any ideas?

Comment: ArcGIS "10.x" refers to eight major and a score of minor releases spanning most of a decade. Can you be more specific on the release? More recent releases have more capable Python implementations.

Comment: Do you mean 1000 records/plants by 1000 datasets?

Comment: Use 20 identical rectangles as pages, each with specific plant name. Use definition query, pages, on large dataset.

Comment: @KadirSahbaz Its 1000 records in total. Species01 can have 30, Species02 can have 150,...datasets and so on.

Comment: @FelixIP Hmm, sounds like a lot of manual work. I just hoped that there was a tool for a situation like this. The example with 20 species and 1.000 records was more theoretical - it could also be 300 species an 50.000 records. So I would have to give every page a name and make (for example) 300 definition querys if I understand correctly what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Workflow below will take same 2 minutes for both 1000 and 1000000 records.

Input:

[image]

- Create single RECTANGLE to cover area of interest.
- multiply it by number of species

`arcpy.Dissolve_management("LCDB","C:/SCRATCH/SCRATCH.gdb/DISSOLVED",dissolve_field="Name_2012", "", multi_part="MULTI_PART"`)

`arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("RECTANGLE", "DISSOLVED", "..PAGES", "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY"`)

Use them to create data driven pages. Apply definition query on original polygons layer:

[image]

Output - one of 18 pages:

[image]